# Can't ping AWS elastic load balancer

Tags: networking, kubernetes, amazon-elb

- I created Load balancer.

  ```
  NAME                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                                 PORT(S)                      AGE 
  open-imis-gateway   LoadBalancer   172.20.102.239   a45b63e62e44b4e239c1381faf6a0216-727219181.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com   443:31394/TCP,80:31355/TCP   3h43m
  ```
- Inbound and Outbound rules allows all traffic.
- I described related [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and all logs clean.

Ping command freeze without response.

```
ping a45b63e62e44b4e239c1381faf6a0216-727219181.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

Please help me to debug this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your VPC Access Control List (ACL) to see if it allows ICMP echo.

You might need to add a rule there also (as well as the regular security group rules).